# What documentation on octavo is available?

Tags: documentation, examples, octavo

Compared with other document classes, the documentation supplied with [`octavo`](http://ctan.org/pkg/octavo) on CTAN is very short.

- Does this documentation really provide the list of custom options and special commands used with `octavo`?
- Are there any other documents which provide more detailed information about how to use this document class?
- Where can I find some examples of finished book that used this class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Glancing through the code (`octavo.dtx`) I can say that the class does not provide special *user-level* commands, and the options defined there are well described in the documentation.  As far as I can see, the aim of the author was to provide a drop-in replacement for the standard LaTeX `book` class with the same interface, but different typographic output.  This goes along the idea of separaton logical markup and the actual typesetting.

Therefore I personally do not see the need in addtional documentation: the authors can use the standard LaTeX manuals, and the TeXnicians can read the (well-commented) source code.

You can easily generate examples yourself.

Comment: Is that `octavo.dtx` file all of the actual code which is used by LaTeX to build the books? I thought that short file was just related to the documentation.

Comment: A `dtx` file is both code and documentation.  This is the literate programming system used by many LaTeX package authors.  You can either typeset it and get a manual and (optionally) commented code, or extract from it the code proper: `cls`, `sty`, `clo` and other files. See the documentation for `docstrip`.

Answer (score 5):

On TeX Live the **octavo** class comes with a TUGboat article by Stefan A. Revets describing it:

```
texdoc octavo
```

will show the document. The PDF is however not of the greatest quality; but the article is publicly available from TUG

http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb23-3-4/tb75revets.pdf

Answer (score 0):

actually the documentation on CTAN is the same as [the one](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb23-3-4/tb75revets.pdf) provided by @egreg. But there is an expanded version [here](http://emis.mi.sanu.ac.rs/zmath/mirror/mirror/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/octavo/octavo.pdf) with extra examples and information, which helped me - I hope it will help others, too.